# Reusing returned user inputted value from class without re-requesting input from user

Tags: java, class, variables, netbeans-7

Relating to Java and using NetBeans 7, I have the following class...

```
     public class StaffLogin2 extends JDialog{
         JPasswordField pf = new JPasswordField();

     public static String  username(){
         String staffName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Username:");
         return staffName;
     }
```

...which requests a username (and later a password in a similar manner) from the user. The result is then passed back to my main code (TillScreen.java) which is a JForm where, along with the password, it is used to gain entry to my till system. The code which gets these credentials from the StaffLogin2 class is as follows...

```
      //imports, constructor etc.
     //loads of private voids up here for buttons, actions etc

     public static void main(String args[]){
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

         public void run() {
                StaffLogin2 validate=new StaffLogin2();//Initialises staff log in  
                String user=validate.username();
                String pass=validate.password();
                //Some other code here to validate credentials...

                if(pass.equals(pWd)){
                new TillScreen().setVisible(true);//Kickstarts the main form...
                }
                else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid username...");
                                   //Main form fails to load, program ends
                }

                }
            ///and some other guff
     }
     }
     //TextFields and other form items declared here....
```

However, I'd like to be able to use the supplied username in a number of other places, for example to be displayed in a text field, and later on to be printed on a receipt. The problem is that when I reference it using...

```
    String somevar=StaffLogin2.username();
```

...the user is prompted to re-enter their information. I'd like to be able to get this username from the class without having to re-ask this question, as the username will need to be used in a number of places. Is there some way I can store this username once it has been used for login purposes?

Apologies for the lengthy question which doubtlessly has a simple answer, or a resounding 'NO!'. I have had a good old root around but can't turn any answers up so far. I think I'm probably missing something obvious, so thanks in advance for any answers, and I'll duck now to avoid the surely incoming clout-around-the-head-for-being-so-dim.  Cheers guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the method that asks the user for their username.  Instead, create a private field in your `StaffLogin2` class like this:

`private String username`

and set it with the returned value from the user like this:

```
public void username()
{
    this.username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Username:");
}
```

Then, reference this field elsewhere with by calling the following `getter` method, which should be in your `StaffLogin2` class:

```
public String getUsername()
{
    return username;
}
```

One other thing - if you're intending this app to be used by more than one person at a time, you'll want to lose the "static" modifiers on your methods and instantiate a class.  Probably a better practice for something like this anyway.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply :). I've done as you said, but I get: "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context" as a red underline below this.username=JOptionPane.... Will it still work if I remove the 'static'? That happily removes the red underline-error!

Comment: Not to worry, have it all sorted now and it's working beautifully. Many thanks for your kind help!

Comment: @GuyStimpson Understand you're too new to upvote, but you can thank me by accepting the answer - just click the check mark underneath the voting buttons.  Glad I could help!

Comment: A-ha! Thought there must be a way for us new 'uns to show appreciation. Done!

Comment: Also I updated my answer to remove `static` from the method signature.  I had copied and pasted your code and forgot to change that

Comment: Lol it did throw me for a bit, but then I re-read your bit about taking it out, so I suppose it was obvious really!